# I can't execute functions from a ViewController in an different one

Tags: ios, swift, function, viewcontroller

Can someone help me execute functions from one VC in another VC. 
The function from the first VC needs to be executed once I press a button in the second VC. 
Im trying with "viewcontroller().function()" function but it's not working properly, printing and basic stuff works but when it comes to stuff like drawing direction it's not working.

The function that draws directions is:

```
func directionToPin() {

    guard let currentPlacemark = currentPlacemark else {
        print("Error, the current Placemark is: \(self.currentPlacemark)")
        return
    }

    let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
    let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(placemark: currentPlacemark)

    directionRequest.source = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()
    directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
    directionRequest.transportType = .walking

    //calculate route
    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    directions.calculate{ (directionsResponse, error) in

        guard let directionsResponse = directionsResponse else {
            if let error = error {
                print("error getting directions: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return
         }

        let route = directionsResponse.routes[0]

        if self.drawedDriection == false {
            self.drawedDriection = true

            if self.didSelectAnnotation == true {
                self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)self.navigationBarController.directionButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "navigationBarDirectionButtonRed")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
                        self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(routeRect), animated: true)
                    }
                } else {
                    self.drawedDriection = false
                    self.mapView.removeOverlays(self.mapView.overlays)
                    if self.didSelectAnnotation == true {
                        self.navigationBarController.directionButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "navigationBarDirectionButtonBlue")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
                    } else {
                        self.navigationBarController.directionButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "navigationBarDirectionButtonGray")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm calling the function in the second VC once I press a button:

```
@IBAction func directionButton(_ sender: Any) {
    MapViewController().directionToPin()
}
```

When I run the app and press the button the **currentPlacemark** is nil, if I run the same function via a button in my first VC (the VC with the directionToPin function inside)

here is my repo if you need it: https://github.com/octavi42/xCodeMapsApp

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @OctaCZO, please share more information / code for better understandig / explanation about your problem then we can find a solution for your issue. Enjoy!

Comment: I hope it is clear now, I edited the question, if you need more infos please ask, thansk!

Comment: If the view controllers are designed in a storyboard `MapViewController()` will never return the instance in the storyboard. You need the real reference with instantiation or a segue.

Comment: I would recommend that you use Delegate instead of calling from another VC.

Comment: There's three ways to have "instances" of two VC's in the same hierarchy: (1) Using a `UINavigationController` - and generally a segue, (2) presenting the second ZVC from the first, sand (3) having the second VC be a child VC of the first. Which are you doing? This is *critical* for a good answer.

Comment: @vadian - I understand, its true that every ViewController has its own Storyboard, the second VC is connected to a xib file, I will read about instantiation and segue and I will try to implement them in my project. If you have any suggestions I would like to hear them.

Comment: @dfd - I think the best way to do this, in my case would with the third way because I use a xib file for my second VC

Comment: @KingT. - can you give me a link with some tutorial about Delegates, thanks

Comment: I agree with everyone else. Delegation. It works best when you have a 1:1 relationship between two VCs, and it's tightly coupled, like you have between a parent and child VC. (BTW, if you had said segue, and you basically wish to update something with the first xvc, I would have suggested passing the VC instance just like you do variables.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to use **Protocols and Delegates** to achieve what you desire.

```
@IBAction func directionButton(_ sender: Any) {
    MapViewController().directionToPin()
}
```

In the above code snippet, you are instantiating a new instance of **MapViewController** which upon initialization resets **currentPlacemark** and hence you've encountered **nil**.

My suggestion is to create a new protocol to communicate from **MapViewController** to **CardViewController** just like this

Add these in **MapViewController.swift**

```
protocol MapNavigationDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didTapDirectionButton()
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    // .... Some code ....

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // . .... Some more code .......
        navigationBarController.mapNavigationDelegate = self
    }
}

extension MapViewController: MapNavigationDelegate {
    func didTapDirectionButton() {
        self.directionToPin()
    }
}
```

Add these in **CardViewController.swift**

```
class CardViewController: UIView {
    // .... Some Code ....
    weak var mapNavigationDelegate: MapNavigationDelegate!

    @IBAction func directionButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.mapNavigationDelegate.didTapDirectionButton()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works and I see the problem I made.

Comment: I have one question tho, what's this code line of code for "navigationBarController.mapNavigationDelegate = self"?

Comment: You have a protocol named **MapNavigationDelegate** and your **MapViewController** conforms to it where you've got an instance of CardViewController. You've a stored property of type **MapNavigationDelegate** in **CardViewController**. Now, you need to specify where it should go looking for **didTapDirectionButton()** on tapping direction button from **CardViewController** which in your case is **MapViewController**. That's why the above line.

Comment: Thanks for help, and for explanation!

Comment: And how could I call functions from first VC in second VC

Comment: You can't call functions in the first VC from the second VC directly. That's when we use Protocols and Delegates. We invoked **directionToPin()** in **MapViewController** from **CardViewController** through **didTapDirectionButton()**

Comment: Yes I understood that but I don’t know how to call functions from CardViewController in my MapViewController

Comment: So the opposite

Comment: You've got an instance of **CardViewController**  as a stored property inside **MapViewController**. You can make use of it.

Comment: That instance is the navigatioBarController, right?

Comment: **@IBOutlet var navigationBarController: CardViewController!** It is of type CardViewController. So you can make use of it.

Comment: So can I call directly the function?

Comment: Of course. Try this. Add this to **CardViewController** 
`func test() { 
    print("test") 
}`. 

Then try to call test from **MapViewController's viewDidLoad()** like this. 
`navigationBarController.test()`. 
You'll see **test** being printed on your debug area.